# Is there a way to bypass <span class=""> and get this data when webscraping in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('span class=""')
print(search.text)

driver.quit()
```

I tried finding this element by class and by tag name. It just returns an error. Is it possible to **scrape** the data in this class or not?

this is the error it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\Commercial Profile.py", line 16, in 
<module>
search = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('span class=""')
File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 530, in find_element_by_tag_name
return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or 
illegal selector was specified
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: When I get that page, there are no `<span>` tags at all.  Where do you see a `<span>`?

Comment: open<div class="UserStream__List"> and go to<div class="UserStreamItems">and then right click on <div role> and then choose edit as html and all the elements specific to the song that's where the span class are.

Comment: `span` is a tag name; `span class=""` is not.  It makes no sense to call `find_element_by_tag_name()` on something that is not a tag name.

Comment: That's not what your code showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
If you wish to locate element with tag name `span` and class name `""` i.e empty class name you should use css selector

```
span[class='']
```

or xpath

```
//span[@class='']
```

`find_element_by_tag_name` method receives element tag name, like `span`, `div`, `a` etc. But there is no tag name `span class=""`
As I guess, your code should be something like this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='']")))
search = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='']")
for el in search:
    print(el.text)
```

Comment: Dang, thanks it worked. it was a stupid oversight on my end.

Comment: It's OKay. Most questions here can be defined in this way :)